# COUNT(*) have null value in column - SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, count

I am trying a query `SQL` in Salesforce to count the number of click per user on one link. However, the count column stays empty even tough my query looks good from a syntax point of view.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT subscriberkey, bannername, COUNT(bannername) AS freq
FROM tablebanner
GROUP by subscriberkey, bannername
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192800/most-clicked-link-by-users-using-sql-query?rq=1

Comment: The query is correct. I attempted it inside my own system with dummy data and results were as expected.  What are the settings for your target DE? If it is a large query, it could take up to 30 minutes or so for it to push data in.

Comment: My bad, I just misspelled the word freq! :)

Comment: would you mind adding an answer to your own question, and accepting it (takes 48 hrs i believe) =)   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a spelling mistake from my side (misspelling of "freq"). Works great now.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are grouping and counting the same column **BannerName** .You need to Group By  Similar values and Count 'Distinct' Values. For example, If you want to count the number of Employees in a particular department.

The table structure being like this:

> **EmployeeName -  DepartmentName**
>
> 1. Employee ABC - Dep A
> 2. Employee XYZ - Dep B
> 3. Employee PQR - Dep A

Here you would group by department name and count EmployeName. Hope this clarifies.